# How do I use camel-azure-servicebus with ClientID & Token

Tags: apache-camel, azureservicebus

I am running Camel inside ActiveMQ trying to connect to an Azure ServiceBus Queue, but `org.apache.camel.component.azure.servicebus.ServiceBusConfiguration` appears only to accept a `connectionString` property. Sadly I don't have and can't get a connection string.

I have been allocated a ClientID, Tenant ID, Secret instead. I can't work out how to implement this with my existing xml based configuration. I have tried to craft a connection string from the details I have but I guess this is not possible.

```xml
    <endpoint id="azureQueueEndpoint" uri="azureServiceBusComponent:iris.705d3ce1-xxxx-4fdf-acb3-xxxxxx" />
    
    <route id="Elexon_IRIS_Route">
        <from uri="azureQueueEndpoint" />
        <to uri="localAMQ:topic:IRIS-Elexon"/>
    </route>
    
    <bean id="azureServiceBusComponent" class="org.apache.camel.component.azure.servicebus.ServiceBusComponent">
            
        <property name="configuration">
            <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.azure.servicebus.ServiceBusConfiguration">
                <property name="connectionString" value="Endpoint=https://elexon-iris.servicebus.windows.net/iris.705d3ce1-xxxx-4fdf-acb3-xxxxxx;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=?????;EntityPath=iris.705d3ce1-xxxx-4fdf-acb3-xxxxxx" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I'm not great with Java and can only really understand xml based config. Currently I get the following error when starting the route;

```
WARN | {"az.sdk.message":"Non-retryable error occurred in AMQP receive link.","exception":"status-code: 401, status-description: InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature., errorContext[NAMESPACE: elexon-iris.servicebus.windows.net. ERROR CONTEXT: N/A, PATH: $cbs, REFERENCE_ID: cbs:receiver, LINK_CREDIT: 0]","linkName":"n/a","entityPath":"n/a"}
ERROR | Errors occurred upstream.
```

I am trying to connect to the ServiceBus and bridge the message feed to an ActiveMQ queue. The is using data from [Elexon-IRIS (free service)](https://bmrs.elexon.co.uk/iris)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I have been able to resolve the connection issue. In part thanks to Chat-GPT for providing an example based on the source code from the com.azure.identity jar.

I will not list all the dependant .jars as there are many...

```xml
<endpoint id="azureQueueEndpoint" uri="azureServiceBusComponent:iris.705d3ce1-xxxx-4fdf-acb3-xxxxxxxx" />

<route id="Elexon_IRIS_Route">
    <from uri="azureQueueEndpoint" />
    <to uri="localAMQ:topic:IRIS-Elexon"/>
</route>

<bean id="azureServiceBusComponent" class="org.apache.camel.component.azure.servicebus.ServiceBusComponent">    
    <property name="configuration">
        <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.azure.servicebus.ServiceBusConfiguration">
            <property name="tokenCredential" ref="azauth" />
            <property name="fullyQualifiedNamespace" value="elexon-iris.servicebus.windows.net" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="azauth" class="com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential">
    <constructor-arg value="AZURE_TENANT_ID"/>
    <constructor-arg value="CLIENT_ID"/>
    <constructor-arg value="CLIENT_SECRET"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClientOptions"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

On connection I now get a valid token;

```
 INFO | Azure Identity => getToken() result for scopes [https://servicebus.azure.net/.default]: SUCCESS
 INFO | {"az.sdk.message":"Scheduling refresh token task.","scopes":"https://servicebus.azure.net/.default"}
 INFO | {"az.sdk.message":"Creating a new receiver link.","connectionId":"MF_77e428_1686394354332","sessionName":"iris.705d3ce1-xxxx-4fdf-acb3-xxxxxxxx","linkName":"iris.705d3ce1-xxxx-4fdf-acb3-xxxxxxxx_76bf6f_1686394354961"}
 INFO | {"az.sdk.message":"Setting next AMQP receive link.","linkName":"iris.705d3ce1-xxxx-4fdf-acb3-0fcb836d2bc9_76bf6f_1686394354961","entityPath":"iris.705d3ce1-xxxx-4fdf-acb3-xxxxxxxx"}
 INFO | {"az.sdk.message":"Returning existing receive link.","connectionId":"MF_77e428_1686394354332","linkName":"iris.705d3ce1-690e-4fdf-acb3-0fcb836d2bc9_76bf6f_1686394354961","entityPath":"iris.705d3ce1-xxxx-4fdf-acb3-xxxxxxxx"}
 INFO | {"az.sdk.message":"onLinkRemoteOpen","connectionId":"MF_77e428_1686394354332","entityPath":"iris.705d3ce1-xxxx-4fdf-acb3-xxxxxxxx","linkName":"iris.705d3ce1-xxxx-4fdf-acb3-xxxxxxxx_76bf6f_1686394354961","remoteSource":"Source{address='iris.705d3ce1-xxxx-4fdf-acb3-xxxxxxxx', durable=NONE, expiryPolicy=SESSION_END, timeout=0, dynamic=false, dynamicNodeProperties=null, distributionMode=null, filter=null, defaultOutcome=null, outcomes=null, capabilities=null}"}
```

I have other problems now though; I have a conflict with the ASM packages. The azure stuff requires `asm-1.0.2` which seem to break the embedded jetty server with;

```
 WARN | Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@25de8898{/admin,file:///root/apache-activemq-5.18.1/webapps/admin/,UNAVAILABLE}
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.createAnnotationParser(AnnotationConfiguration.java:502) ~[jetty-annotations-9.4.51.v20230217.jar:9.4.51.v20230217]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations(AnnotationConfiguration.java:416) ~[jetty-annotations-9.4.51.v20230217.jar:9.4.51.v20230217]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:346) ~[jetty-annotations-9.4.51.v20230217.jar:9.4.51.v20230217]
```

This was fixed by removing the `asm-1.0.2.jar` and old json-smart.jar

Though the broker starts. The biggest problem (for another post) is this error I now get presumably when receiving a message and trying to send it to AMQ:

```
WARN | Cannot determine specific JmsMessage type to use from body class. Will use generic JmsMessage. Body class: com.azure.core.util.BinaryData. If you want to send a POJO then your class might need to implement java.io.Serializable, or you can force a specific type by setting the jmsMessageType option on the JMS endpoint.
```

Which was fixed by adding `<convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>` to the route like and turning into valid JSON;

```xml
<route id="Elexon_IRIS_Route">
    <from uri="azureQueueEndpoint" />
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
    <unmarshal><json/></unmarshal>
    <to uri="localAMQ:queue:IRIS-Elexon"/>
</route>
```